# How to style just one of multiple unordered lists?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list which I am using for my navigation. I am then using another unordered list in my main page for a list of equipment that was used for my photography.

When I go to style only my top navigation `ul`, it starts styling the `ul` and `li` of the equipment. Code below (not finished it yet, but am in process of creating horizontal menu):

**HTML**

Navigation:

```
<nav id="page-navigation">
      <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="_portfolio/photography.html" title="Photography">Photography</a></li>
                </ul>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Equipment:

```
<h1>Equipment:</h1>
  <ul id="equipment">
      <li>Canon EOS 600D.</li>
      <li>Canon EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM Lens.</li>
      <li>Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 Lens.</li>
      <li>Adobe Lightroom CC.</li>
  </ul>
```

**CSS**

Navigation:

```
#page-navigation ul, li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Equipment:

```
#equipment li, ul
{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin-top: 0.1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

Whatever I style in the navigation, it goes into the equipment too and vice versa. I thought the idea of having an id means it will only style that id, not every `li` or `ul` it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on mobile right now but your selectors are wrong. '#page-navigation ul, li' selects page-navigation -> ul AND every Li tag. Just remove the comma and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```css
#page-navigation ul, li {}
```

Should be read as:

```css
#page-navigation ul, 
li {
}
```

You're asking to style *any* `ul` under `#page-navigation`, and *any* `li` on the page.

If you want to limit yourself to `li` tags under `#page-navigation`, you'd say:

```css
#page-navigation ul, 
#page-navigation li {
}
```

If you only want the *top* level of each to be styled, say so:

```css
#page-navigation > ul, 
#page-navigation > ul > li {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what the comma is doing in your selectors. It separates the elements to select, so `#page-navigation ul, li` means apply the following rules to any `ul` element that is a descandant of the element with the ID of `#page-navigation` AND also apply them to ALL `li` elements on the page.

The same goes for your `#equipment li, ul` selector. That means, apply the follow rules to all `li` elements that are descendants of the element with the ID of `#equipment` AND all `ul` elements on the page.

What you probably want are `#page-navigation ul li` and `#equipment li`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the first li in your list write:

```
#page-navigation > li {
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   margin-top: 0.1em;
   margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

For the second li:

```
#page-navigation li > li {
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   margin-top: 0.1em;
   margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

To style the ul:

```
#page-navigation ul {
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   margin-top: 0.1em;
   margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```